# Laravel One-to-one Relationship Returns null on some data

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have two related tables and I need to fetch some data using laravel's eloquent. Here's my [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR8yc.png). 
I have created two models: User and UserCurrentPosition defining relation between those two.

**User.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function position()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserCurrentPosition', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

**UserCurrentPosition.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class UserCurrentPosition extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function scopeDistance($query, $dist, $location)
    {
        return $query->select(DB::raw('ST_X(location) AS longitude, ST_Y(location) AS latitude, ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(location, POINT('.$location.')) AS dist'))
            ->havingRaw('dist < '.$dist)
            ->orderBy('dist', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

I intended to get name and phone from users table and longitude, latitude, and distance from the other table. Here's what i've done:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\User;
use App\UserCurrentPosition;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers;

class DriverController extends Controller
{
    use Helpers;
    public function __construct(User $user, UserCurrentPosition $userpos, UserDetail $userdetail)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->userdetail = $userdetail;
        $this->userpos = $userpos;
    }

    public function getNearby(Request $request)
    {
        $dist = $request->get('dist');
        $lon = $request->get('lon');
        $lat = $request->get('lat');

        return $this->userpos
            ->with('user')
            ->distance($dist, $lon.', '.$lat)
            ->take(3)
            ->get()
            ->toJson();
    }
}
```

But the output goes like this:

```
[
  {
    "longitude": 112.745978,
    "latitude": -7.286319,
    "dist": 5824.995681344659,
    "user": null
  },
  {
    "longitude": 112.744166,
    "latitude": -7.310827,
    "dist": 6862.04670609193,
    "user": null
  },
  {
    "longitude": 112.73957,
    "latitude": -7.249031,
    "dist": 7394.147599012171,
    "user": null
  }
]
```

I want to get user data along with longitude, latitude, and dist instead of "null". How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u check please your CurrentPositionTable that it contain user_id foreign  key .. may be you have spelling mistake in currentpositiontable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add user_id in select query

```
public function scopeDistance($query, $dist, $location)
    {
        return $query->select(DB::raw('user_id , ST_X(location) AS longitude, ST_Y(location) AS latitude, ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(location, POINT('.$location.')) AS dist '))
            ->havingRaw('dist orderBy('dist', 'ASC');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is so easy, you are using the wrong foreign keys configuration:

**Laravel offical documentation:**

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

You are using the same config in both models:

*UserCurrentPosition.php*

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

*User.php*

```
public function position()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserCurrentPosition', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

To fix the problem I suggest you to check the keys.
Marco

Comment: You can have 'same config in both models' see  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: I tried without specifying keys and other combination (swtiching user_id and id, etc) but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You simply just put this code on your Specific file

**User.php**

```
public function position()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserCurrentPosition');
    }
```

**UserCurrentPosition.php**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Comment: yes I know, usually it works but in my case, it didn't. Turns out i have to specify user_id in my scope like mohamed ali said.

Comment: in your user table Primary key is id and position table it becomes user_id as a foreign key then my code is work otherwise you have to assign manually in code.